# Is there a way to export a function from R to Excel?

Tags: r, excel, export-to-excel

For work, I've been asked to export a function that I create to R.  Say that I have created a model, inventively called 'model'.  So, I create a function as follows:

```
f.m <- function(x_) {
       return ( predict (model, x = x_ )$ y ) }
```

Is there a way I can export this function to Excel?  I suppose it would, for example, go into column B, while the inputs x_ would go into column A.  Thank you.

Comment: You should make your question much more detailed. It is unclear what you are asking. For example, you may simply be looking to save the object returned by your function as two columns in a csv that you write.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit broad, but in the interest of pointing you in the right direction, here are two projects which I know of:

- There's the `BERT` toolkit [available here](https://bert-toolkit.com/)
- There is the `RExcel` project, [available for download here](http://rcom.univie.ac.at/download.html)

I can't comment at length on how good they are, but I did tinker with BERT once and it seems to work.  [Here's a blog](https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-million-ways-to-connect-r-and-excel/) on the topic of getting Excel and R to talk to each other.